# How to avoid large up/down terms in R earth package?

Tags: r, regression, multicollinearity

I realize this question might be specific to the 'earth' package, but the problem itself may be a little more generic.

Specifically, if I do a fairly constrained fit of a linear regression with earth with many predictors (>5000, maybe 200,000 rows), I get a model that looks like this:

```
> m.orig$coefficients
                             d.train[,5777]
(Intercept)                    -0.0000911973208
ratio_feature                  -0.0000072012117
disp_size                       0.0003088136492
wdisp_size                     -0.0003087910869
secondary                      -0.0000279230109
timing                          0.0000003378173
```

Right away I notice that the coefficients for disp_size and wdisp_size are:

- The largest in magnitude (the same problem could manifest itself for smallest, too)
- Almost equivalent, but of opposite sign

Fortunately, I know something about the disp_size and wdisp_size predictors, and it disturbs me.  Basically wdisp_size is *almost* the same as disp_size but it incorporates a little bit of extra information (that is better expressed as yet another predictor which didn't get included in the model due to stopping criteria).

I have several problems with this situation:

- The magnitudes of those two predictors are large to begin with.  So we are in effect both smashing down the size (via the subtraction) and stripping off the "extra" information which would better be expressed through the other predictor that didn't get picked
- Two variables got swallowed by this, causing us to stop earlier than we would have (i.e. another more helpful variable might have come in had we been able to not pick these two opposing, large-sized predictors)

Is there any reasonable way to try and stop things like this from happening, short of doing what I'm doing now, which is a full residual analysis and then trawling through the predictors?  This is kind of nuts.  At some level I don't have complete control of the features I'm being given, so there's nothing to stop more like this from creeping in.

Any advice would be most welcome.

**Update**

As a follow-up to this, I should note that manually removing the two opposing predictors from the set that could be considered resulted in a significantly better test set result.  It's night and day better.  Kind of amazing that something like this could have such a drastic effect!

Comment: What kind of model are you fitting?

Comment: Ah, sorry will update to mention.  Plain old linear regression.

Comment: This isn't really about R at all, so I am voting to leave it open.

Comment: Thanks for updating the tags.  First post, so wasn't sure how to categorize it.  And yes, you're right, it's a more general question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The key bit in your question is

> Basically wdisp_size is almost the same as disp_size

Therefore, it is almost certain that you have collinearity.  You can check this using condition indexes and proportion of variance explained but it's pretty likely.

There are various solutions to this issue. If you really want both variables in the model, you can use ridge regression. If that's not necessary, then just drop one of the variables.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  In this particular case I chose to drop both and leave the variable that actually has domain-specific meaning, and that improved things.  I also looked at condition indexes (R package 'perturb'), and that uncovered a few more problems which I am following up on.  Thanks again.